# Python networkx memory error on small dataset

Tags: python, networkx

I have a relatively small dataset consisting of ~100k edges and ~7000 nodes. I am trying to use two algorithms to find communities within my dataset. I added the edges and proceeded to run an algorithm that was implemented here: http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/#as-python-module

Data is basically as follows:

Node1,Node2

Node1 is connected to node2 and the graph is undirected.

But the program just runs for a bit then gives me a memory error. I know it works because I tested it on a small dataset and it works properly but it's giving me a memory error. I don't know a lot about these algorithms but I was under the impression that the dataset I have is really small and I am running it on my personal home computer. Is this just a problem with the implementation itself or due to my machine's limitations?

Would any of you have an idea as to how to get this to work (i.e. another piece of software or algorithm) besides running it on a server with a lot more memory?

Thanks!

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<wingdb_compile>", line 65, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\layout.py", line 242, in fruchterman_reingold_layout
    pos=_fruchterman_reingold(A,dim,pos_arr,fixed,iterations)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\layout.py", line 280, in _fruchterman_reingold
    delta = np.zeros((pos.shape[0],pos.shape[0],pos.shape[1]),dtype=A.dtype)
MemoryError
```

Comment: @Paul: Error seems to happen while trying to draw the network. If you don't need to draw, then remove those part, try again and see if you get an error.

Comment: It's actually the layout part of the drawing - which is creating a large numpy matrix in this case - that is filling the memory.  You probably won't be able to see much when drawing 7000 nodes and 100K edges anyway...so skip the drawing part and see if it fits in memory then.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but `NetworkX` still has memory issues especially when dealing with algorithms like `communities`.

**Check out** [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance). It is a `python` package that boasts much faster performance than `NetworkX`

I am not affiliated with `graph-tool`. It has solved memory problems for me in terms of running algorithms on large networks.

**Try converting** your `nodes` to `integers` if you have not done so already. I have found that nodes that are labelled as strings can take up a lot of memory.

Happy networking